# Django query Select X from Table where Y = Z

Tags: python, sql, django

It's just yet hard to me to clearly understand the way that Django makes queries.

I have two tables:

Table A:

```
+----+-----+----+
| id |code |name|
+----+-----+----+
```

Table B:

```
+----+----+
| id |name|
+----+----+
```

Value of `name` of both tables can be equal (or not). What I need to do is to get the value of Table A column `code`, by comparing both tables' `name` if Table B does match with Table A in any row.

Example:

Table A:

```
+----+----+----+
| id |code|name|
+----+----+----+
| 4  | A1 |John|
+----+----+----+
```

Table B:

```
+----+----+
| id |name|
+----+----+
| 96 |John|
+----+----+
```

So, by comparing `John` (B) with `John` (A), I need `A1` to be returned, since it's the `code` result in the same row that matches on Table A.

In conclusion I need a Django code to do the query:

```
a_name = 'John'

SELECT code FROM Table_A WHERE name = a_name
```

Take into account that I only know the value of table B, therefore I can't get the value of `code` by Table A's `name`.

Comment: The question is basic but very well detailed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use Django's `values` and `values_list` methods.  You provide the *field* name you want data for.

```
values = Table_A.objects.filter(name=B_name).values('code')
```

This returns a dictionary with only the `code` values in it.  From the django documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Or you can use `values_list` to format the result as a list.

```
values = Table_A.objects.filter(name=B_name).values_list('code')
```

This will return a list of tuples, even if you only request one field.  The django documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

To try to make this a little more robust, you first get your list of named values from Table_B.  Supplying `flat=True` creates a true list, as values_list will give you a list of tuples.  Then use the list to filter on Table_A.  You can return just the code or the code and name.  As written, it returns a flat list of user codes for every matching name in Table A and Table B.

```
b_names_list = Table_B.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
values =Table_A.objects.filter(name__in=b_names_list).values_list('code', flat=True)
```

Comment: @GonzaloD'ambra How does it work ? The author of this answer is simply getting the value of code from table A if it has a name `John` but you said in your question that you want to compare the two tables for value `John` and if that is found in both tables then you wanna get code in table A.

Comment: QuerySets are built iteratively.  The django documentation has a good description here,https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/.  The section about filtered querysets being unique has a decent small example.  You can chain as many filters/queryset generating methods together as needed to get to your desired object.

Comment: This was the best answer so far. I think it can work for me. Thank you! Now I just need to know how to get the clean data from that Query dictionary, in order to use the value of "code"

Comment: @Ahtisham the answer is right, it is returning the value of "code"

Comment: @GonzaloD'ambra Other answers also return the value of `code`. And they do it just as you suggested in your question. Get the code only if two names in each 
 table are same.

Comment: @Ahtisham  I've updated the answer to more fully answer the question.  I made him aware of a django method that provides the functionality he is looking for.  The edit allows you to not need to know any of the data in any of the tables.  It simply searches in the two tables and provides codes.  It does answer his question and he doesn't need to perform a large loop to get his information.  It's just one django query built from multiple QuerySet definitions.

Comment: @Rachel What is the point of getting list of names ? He is just asking to find a single name `John`.

Comment: @Ahtisham When I made the assumption he knew the name he was looking for, you were very concerned that the answer didn't fit the question.  This answer will find the code for everyone with matches in Tables A and B.  I removed the assumption that he knew the data he was looking for.  He can alter the query as he sees fit to fit his needs.  This does answer the question of, how do I get a field from one table when I need to match on a different field.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose name of your tables are `A` and `B` respectively then:

```
try:
    obj = A.objects.get(name='John')
    if B.objects.filter(name='John').exists():
        print obj.code # found a match and now print code.      
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose `TableA` and `TableB` are django models. Then, your query, may look like this:

```
a_name = 'John'

it_matches_on_b = ( Table_B
                   .objects
                   .filter(  name = a_name )
                   .exists()
                  )

fist_a = ( Table_A
            .objects
            .filter(  name = a_name )
            .first()
          )

your_code = fist_a.code if it_matches_on_b and fist_a != None else None
```

I don't comment code because it is self-explanatory. But write questions on comments if you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
B_name = ‘whatever’
Table_A.objects.filter(name = B_name)
```

The above is the basic query if you want to get the db fields values connected to name value from Table_A, based on the fact that you know the name value of Table_B

To get the value:

```
obj = Table_A.objects.get(name = B_name)

print(obj.name)
print(obj.code) # if you want the 'code' field value
```

Comment: thank you @Zollie , I already know that code. But now, how can I get the column "code" value of Table_A? Of the same row that your code returned of course

Comment: @GonzaloD'ambra How is this answer comparing the two tables ? It just gives you the result  of `code` in A.

Comment: @Ahtisham - I think his purpose with his question was only to know how to get a particular value from tables based on a known value. It could get as complex as anybody wants but basically the person who asked this question only wanted to learn getting particular values from a table... So never mind...

Comment: @Zollie This is what he said: "What I need to do is to get the value of Table A column code, by comparing both tables' name if Table B does match with Table A in any row."

Comment: @Ahtisham - The Poster most probably wanted to ask smply 'filtering and getting a value from another table based on another value', instead of that he wrote 'comparing two values' and so on, you see... sometimes these things just happen and can be misunderstood. English is not the first language of many people here.

Comment: It’s also true that the poster does not have yet enough reputation to upvote anybody, so I’ll also upvote his question since it was quite well detailed on his question.